# How to dynamically switch views using Knockout templates

Tags: templates, knockout.js, duration, digital

I'm working on a digital signage module for our intranet. I'm trying to add videos into the mix. I want to play videos first, then play a slide show. I will eventually have this loop. I start by calling the startSequence function, which counts down from the video duration. You can observe the console.log (F12). Then I'm changing the selectedTemplate observable from 1 to 2 , after the videos have played I call the showSlides function, but my view is not detecting the change. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/sju07tkk/66/)

Do I need a computed observable? -instead of this...

`<div>
    <!-- ko if: $root.selectedTemplate() == 1 -->
      <div data-bind="template: { name: 'videoScript', foreach: $root.dynamicVideos() }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $root.selectedTemplate() == 2 -->
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'imageScript' }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're passing string template names to the template binding.

Fortunately, the binding also supports passing observable strings, or even functions! You can find its [documentation on knockout's template page](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used).

Here's an example using a computed template name:

```js
const index = ko.observable(0);
const loop = () => index((index() + 1) % 2);

const activeTemplate = ko.pureComputed(() => 
  index() ? "t-slideshow" : "t-video"
);

ko.applyBindings({ activeTemplate });

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: activeTemplate"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="t-slideshow">
  <h2>I'm a slide show! </h2>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="t-video">
  <h2>I'm a video! </h2>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you user3297291! Here's a new working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/b72p5o4f/)